# Send and receive data in same ajax request with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is the best way to send data and receive a response dependent on that data?

Consider the PHP file used for the request:

```
$test = $_POST['test'];

echo json_encode($test);
```

I have tried unsucessfully to achieve this with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{test : worked}',
    url: 'ajax/getDude.php',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lose the quotes to pass the object:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {test : worked},
  url: 'ajax/getDude.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this

```
data: '{test : worked}'
```

try

```
data: {"test" : worked} // Worked being your data you want to pass..
 data: {"test" : "worked"} // Else enclose worked in quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you're submitting a string rather than a json object - change `data: '{test : worked}'` to `data: {test : 'worked'}`